# Unable to redirect to fitbit OAuth2 endpoint

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I am trying to get authorize from Fitbit. when I use Oauth2.0

frontend angular4

```
getAuthFromFitbit() {
this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + "/fitbit").subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res.json());
});}
```

backend node.js

[image: IDE capture of code]

then I got this problem:
[image: Eror message]

Comment: can you try add method res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');

Comment: didn't work, the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see in the browser console is coming from a fitbit request, not from your server. Setting headers on your server will not help much in your case.

Comment: Thanks, So if I want to solve this problem.  I need to contact with Fitbit, right?

Answer (score -1):

This is a Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue. You need to disable CORS in your browser.

Comment: I do do this in Firefox, sadly failure again.

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: open about:config  chage security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

Answer (score -1):

i use this when front and back is not in same server.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
})
```

Could you try this.

Comment: damn that's all of my knowledge about node. sorry